# Any mobile-friendly Credit Card billing solutions for mobile sites similar to Bango?

Tags: mobile, in-app-purchase, payment-gateway, payment, recurring-billing

Are there any mobile-friendly Credit Card billing solutions for **mobile sites** similar to Bango?

The advantages of Bango I have seen compared to regular Credit Card solutions that make it considerably "mobile-friendly" are:

1. 1) It does not require the user to enter their full name and billing
   address to make a payment.  The user is only required to enter their
   Credit Card number, expiration date, and CVC code (if they are in
   the U.S., they will also have to enter their Zip Code).  That is significantly less input than is normally required for Credit Card payments, which is a big plus on small mobile key pads.
2. After a user makes an initial Credit Card payment, their details
   are stored by Bango, and the next time the user needs to make a
   payment with the same Credit Card, they just have to click a single
   link and it processes the payment on their stored Credit Card. 
   Needless to say, this is very convenient for mobile users as it is
   analogous to Direct Carrier Billing as far as the user is concerned since they won't need to input any details.

The downside with Bango is that their fees are higher than others, all payments must be processed via their site and branding, there is a high minimum ($1.99) and a low maximum ($30) on how much you can charge users, and you need to pay a monthly fee on top of the high transaction costs.

It is due to the downsides mentioned above that I am looking for an alternative solution that also does the advantages 1) and 2) above.  Is there anything like that?  I looked at JunglePay and they do neither 1) nor 2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We, [Balanced](https://www.balancedpayments.com), have simliar functionality to what you're looking for. Card number, and expiration are the only required information. However the more information you gather the better that fraud detection can happen, only asking for the minimum could open you up to chargebacks and the cost associated with them.

The second requirement you mention is a feature called [card tokenization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenization_%28data_security%29) and most card processors should support this functionality.

Balanced is not inherently mobile focussed. It's a REST API so whatever you serve to the customer is up to you. You, as the developer, would create a webpage that takes in the card information, [tokenizes it securely](https://www.balancedpayments.com/docs/js), and then submits the token to your server where logic in your application makes the charge whenever you're ready.

Comment: Very, very interesting!  So if I understand what you are saying, I can replicate exactly what Bango offers by using Balanced, and the only difference is that I would have to program everything on my end via your API?  Surely there's a catch, because it sounds too good to be true!

Comment: I believe you could, Balanced gives you all the basic functionality to bring in payments and pay them out again. If you have a specific scenario in mind beyond the one in the original question, ask it and I'll do my best to show how it could all work together.

Comment: Will do, thanks.  So do you need a Merchant Account and Payment Gateway to use Balanced, or do you guys handle all of that?  Is their a monthly fee, or just the transaction fees?  How are payouts to us merchants made?  Thanks again!

Comment: Just sign up and you're good to go, we collect enough info to create a merchant account at the time you apply. No monthly fee, just the txn fees. Payouts are done via next-day ACH. We are looking at also adding international ACH, if you want additional payout methods ask on github - https://github.com/balanced/balanced-api/issues

Comment: Thanks Marshall, you've been a great help!